# angular 2/4/5 Bootstrap 4 resizable column so a 2 column layout has a resize bar in the middle?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a bootstrap 4 layout in my angular 5 application with 2 columns...
One takes up 8 columns, and the other takes up 4 columns.
In the middle I have a border that is thick that I want to be 'grabbable' by the user so they can resize so that they can drag towards the right towards the edge of the screen to make the originally 8 column to take up the whole width of the screen and all of its child elements. (the 4 column basically gets resized away).

Is this possible with Angular 4/5? If not, are there plugins that or extensions that would help do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only thing I have came across is this : 
https://codepen.io/ericfillipe/pen/RGNaRK

create set of columns like this

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="grid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Not sure about angular but might required to wrap this up.